# Can I make a script that creates a schedule?

Tags: google-sheets

I know this is a generic question.

My wife has about 60 individuals she needs to see every month. Scheduling takes a large portion of her time.

Each individual has their own needs. Times they cannot meet for one reason or another. There are also individuals that need to be seen multiple times a month while others are once a month.

What I would like to do is create a roster for each individual on a page and then it will create a schedule for her that reduces travel distance.

Is this possible in Google sheets scripting?

Comment: Yes, google sheets appscript can access google calendars

Comment: abstract unanswerable question...

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely create a script for what your wife needs to do. The Apps Script methods you need to use will depend on what you want to do specifically and how you are going to accomplish this.

For instance you can use the methods from the `SpreadsheetApp` class in order to pull the data from the specific sheets and cells and the methods from the `CalendarApp` class to create the Google Calendar events based in the information from the spreadsheet.

You could even use the methods from the `MailApp` class in order to send emails to confirm to the individuals that the event was created.

In addition to all that you could also get the input data to create the events from a form that would need to be filled by each individual, and then just process the information from the [responses spreadsheet](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/139706?hl=en&ref_topic=6063592#zippy=%2Cview-all-responses-in-a-spreadsheet) and create the events based on the criteria you will be using to decide which event goes first.

I leave below some examples of some methods you can use for this.

References:

- [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)
- [Method: getCurrentCell()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getcurrentcell)
- [CalendarApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app)
- [Method: createEvent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#createeventtitle,-starttime,-endtime)
- [MailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app)
- [Method: sendEmail()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body)